# Data Formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: Graph Plotted]

In the above graph you can see the data automatically starts from 0 but it doesn't make sense for the limit to start from 0 so i wanted to format my data such that excel doesn't extrapolate the data.
I've also added the data table for suggestions to get the necessary output.

[image: Data Table]

Comment: Why doesn't make sense for the limit to start from 0? What if there was no precipitation, or an amount less than 1.0?

Comment: Does the above graph made from below data table? The limit does not start from 0 when I made a [Line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZhZZ.jpg) from the data table.

Comment: @EmilyHua Yes i used this data table it's quite strange seeing we got different results do you know what could have caused that?

Comment: @K7AAY In my context i am calculating the amount of a particular substance and this is all the data i have so i don't want it to start from 0 but rather reflect the data as it is

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab, please right click the chart > Select "Limit" > Edit > reselect the data range (8 cells of Number "2.5") for Series values. Besides, click "Hidden and Empty Cells" > Show empty cells as "Gaps".

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab When check the data range for Limit series values does not help, maybe you could copy the table to a new blank worksheet, and just keep values, try to create a Line chart again.

Comment: @EmilyHua Thanks a lot this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You've used one more cell for the Y values of the "Limit" series than for the other Y values, starting with the cell that says "Limit". Excel plots the text value "Limit" as zero, and then it plots the extra cell at the end as one more value of 2.5, beyond the rest of the data.

Comment: If excel had plotted the text value as 0 then why is there a key for line and why didn't the others start from 0 as well? It's the same in every row so why did it treat the last row differently?

Comment: I'll bet the Limit series was added to the graph after it already correctly contained A and B. In the dialog, the series name is a separate input box than the series values. After selecting the cell with the Limit label, you selected the row of cells containing the Limit values, and inadvertently included the cell that had the label. It's easy enough to do this. But it's also easy enough to check and to fix. So... wasn't this the case?